# Angular how to use formarray on object type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to setup a reactive where user can dynamically enter inputs. I could it for an actual array, however, I would like to do the same for object type.

for this:

```
dynamic_attributes: {
    "default['tets']['agents']['locks']": true,
    "override['simple']['stuff']": "'dummy'"
    }
}
```

I want something like allowing a user to enter input fields dynamically using formarray or anything that works in reactive forms

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a **custom form control that has an array as its input value**. A possible template to get the values of the array can be a component with an input and an "+" button that will add another input (representing an element of your array) and so on.

[image]

Read this [guide to create a custom form control in Angular](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/).